Rsync unable to create hard links of symlinks
I have long used rsync to back up various directories on my production servers. I do "incremental" backups using rsync's --link-dest flag. This causes rsync to check the directory of the previous backup and if the file in question hasn't changed, it just creates a hard link to the previous file in the destination directory. This has worked for years.
I recently upgraded my Mac and as a result I am now running MacOS Sonoma 14.5 which is a much newer version than on my old Mac.
My rsync backups now fail with rsync: [generator] failed to hard-link /Volumes/Data03/backup/etc-2024-0925-1448/localtime with localtime: Operation not supported (45).
I get this error for every symlink in the previous backup directory.
This can be replicated in the shell:
$ touch x.1
$ ln -s x.1 x.2
$ ln -P x.2 x.3. # -P means link to the symlink, not the symlink's target
ln: x.3: Operation not supported

Any idea of how to fix this?
TIA
Edit - Additional information:
After additional testing, I have discovered that creating hard links to symlinks works on APFS volumes. The exact same shell commands shown above are successful on an APFS volume, for whatever that's worth.

What format is the Data03 volume?

Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled)

What version of rsync are you running on your Mac?

I've tried both 2.6.9 (Apple), and 3.3.0 (Homebrew). I don't think the rsync version really matters since I can duplicate the problem from the shell.

If this is a hfs+ problem, the question title and text may need a rewrite.

I'm open. What would you suggest?
